# Magento 2: What is Purpose of .travis.yml file?

Tags: magento2, travis

In Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0. I have below content in `.travis.yml`

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - mysql-server-5.6
    - mysql-client-core-5.6
    - mysql-client-5.6
    - postfix
language: php
php:
  - 5.6
  - 7.0
env:
  global:
    - COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=~/bin
    - INTEGRATION_SETS=3
  matrix:
    - TEST_SUITE=unit
    - TEST_SUITE=integration INTEGRATION_INDEX=1
    - TEST_SUITE=integration INTEGRATION_INDEX=2
    - TEST_SUITE=integration INTEGRATION_INDEX=3
    - TEST_SUITE=static
cache:
  apt: true
  directories: $HOME/.composer/cache
matrix:
  exclude:
    - php: 7.0
      env: TEST_SUITE=static
before_install: ./dev/travis/before_install.sh
install: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
before_script: ./dev/travis/before_script.sh
script: 
  - cd dev/tests/$TEST_SUITE
  - test $TEST_SUITE = "static" && TEST_FILTER='--filter "Magento\\Test\\Php\\LiveCodeTest"' || true
  - phpunit $TEST_FILTER
```

What is exact purpose of this? What it does? May be used for testing?

Answer (score 2):

> Travis CI is a hosted continuous integration platform that is free for
>   all open source projects hosted on Github. With just a file called
>   `.travis.yml` containing some information about our project, we can
>   trigger automated builds with every change to our code base in the
>   master branch, other branches or even a pull request.

For more info you can visit [link](https://docs.travis-ci.com)